# How do I get split-screen mode for Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: visual-web-developer

I want to view both the preview of the page I am working on and the code, so as I edit the code I can instantly view the changes I have made.

Comment: I just went ahead and uninstalled all that junk. Testing out Kompozer, trying to figure out split-screen mode.

Comment: What you call junk is actually called documentation, if you read it you see how easy it is to split the view. Kompozer is not really a solution, the site and name gives a feeling that it's junk. So, did you basically install it to continue figuring out split-screen mode?

Answer (score 1):

There should be [Design] | [Split] [Source] buttons at the bottom of the edit area.

[image: Design, Split and Source]

The next question is often how to make it split vertically instead of horizontally. In the Tools -> Options dialog check "Show All Settings" then also check "Split views vertically" in the "HTML Designer" section.

[image]